# How to Write Structured Streaming Data into Cassandra with PySpark?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

I want to write spark structured streaming data into cassandra. My spark version is 2.4.0.

I've research some post and some of uses DataStax enterprise platform.
I've didn't use it and found a method `foreachBatch` which helps for write streaming data to sink.

I've review a docs based on the databricks [site](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/structured-streaming/examples.html#write-to-azure-sql-data-warehouse-using-foreachbatch-in-python). And try it own.

This is the code I've written:

```
parsed = parsed_opc \
    .withWatermark("sourceTimeStamp", "10 minutes") \
    .dropDuplicates(["id", "sourceTimeStamp"]) \
    .groupBy(
        window(parsed_opc.sourceTimeStamp, "4 seconds"),
        parsed_opc.id
    ) \
    .agg({"value": "avg"}) \
    .withColumnRenamed("avg(value)", "avg")\
    .withColumnRenamed("window", "sourceTime") 

def writeToCassandra(writeDF, epochId):
  writeDF.write \
    .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")\
    .mode('append')\
    .options(table="opc", keyspace="poc")\
    .save()

parsed.writeStream \
    .foreachBatch(writeToCassandra) \
    .outputMode("update") \
    .start()
```

The schema of the `parsed` dataframe is:

```
root
 |-- sourceTime: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- start: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |    |-- end: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- avg: double (nullable = true)
```

I can succesfully write this streaming df to console like this:

```
 query = parsed \
  .writeStream \
  .format("console")\
  .outputMode("complete")\
  .start()
```

And the outputs as follows in console:

```
+--------------------+----+---+
|          sourceTime|  id|avg|
+--------------------+----+---+
|[2019-07-20 18:55...|Temp|2.0|
+--------------------+----+---+
```

So, when writing to the console, thats OK. 
But when I query in the `cqlsh` there is no record appended to the table.

This is the table create script in cassandra:

```
CREATE TABLE poc.opc ( id text, avg float,sourceTime timestamp PRIMARY KEY );
```

So, Can you tell me what is wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have any errors when you're trying to write to Cassandra?

Comment: I am not sure. But I didn't see any errors in terminal when program runs.

Comment: I am running this programs in jupyter notebook. And the runtime logs printed in the terminal. Are there any path to look for logs file, may be I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

After working on subject I've found the solution.

Looking to the terminal logs closely, I figured it out that there is an error log which is:
 `com.datastax.spark.connector.types.TypeConversionException: Cannot convert object [2019-07-20 18:55:00.0,2019-07-20 18:55:04.0] of type class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema to java.util.Date.`

It is because, when doing `window` operation in spark, It adds a struct to the schema on timestamp column which is in this case `sourceTime`. 
The schema of the `sourceTime` looks like this:

```
sourceTime: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- start: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |    |-- end: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

But I've created a column in cassandra which is already `sourceTime` but it expects only one timestamp value. If looking to the error, it tries to send `start` and `end` timeStamp parameter which are not exist in cassandra table.

So, selecting this columns from `parsed` dataframe solved the problem:
`cassandra_df = parsed.select("sourcetime.start", "avg", "sourcetime.end", "id")`.